# Pygame - What happens if you blit a surface with a rect smaller than the surface?

Tags: python, pygame, rect

In this `blit` call

```
screen = pygame.Surface(640, 480)
bgsurf = pygame.Surface(640, 480)
new_rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, 80, 80)

screen.blit(bgsurf, new_rect, new_rect)
```

how pygame decides which portion of `bgsurf` it will copy to the screen in the `new_rect` area?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the pygame docs:

> blit(source, dest, area=None, special_flags = 0) -> Rect
>
> Draws a source Surface onto this Surface. The draw can be positioned
> with the dest argument. Dest can either be **pair of coordinates
> representing the upper left corner of the source**. **A Rect can also be
> passed as the destination and the topleft corner of the rectangle will
> be used as the position for the blit.** The size of the destination
> rectangle does not effect the blit.
>
> An optional area rectangle can be passed as well. This represents a
> smaller portion of the source Surface to draw.

So as you can see, pygame would blit the whole surface at (0,0).
If you want to blit a part of surface, you need to pass in the area Rect.

EDIT:

In your case, it will blit the subsurface given by new_rect onto screen where the top-left corner will be placed at (0,0).